# How to draw a square in java?

Tags: java

**Here is what I have to do:**

> You are to write a program that draws a square composed of # signs onto a grid. The user will enter the size (in the length of the sides), the x-coordinate, and the y-coordinate of the bottom-left corner
>   of the square on the grid as command-line parameters to program, in that order.
>
> In other words, the three values will be stored in the String array args at the start of the program, as the values `args[0],
>   args[1], and args[2]`. You can use the command `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the String into an int. Assume that the input parameters are valid ints.

**For example**, in the Interactions pane of DrJava:

run Que s ti on 2 5 1 1
means that we want to draw a square with side length 5 whose bottom-left corner is at position (1, 1).
All distances in this question are in number of characters. By default, the program should print the
square onto a 15x15 grid, but if the square wouldn’t fit, the grid has to be extended accordingly.

I'm trying to build my program in three steps.

1. write the code to display the axes properly.
2. build a solution where the square always fits into the 15x15 grid.
3. How to extend the program to make it work for larger squares or for squares that are too much shifted to fit into the 15x15 grid.

**Here are my codes so far:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class drawS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = ask.nextInt();
        int i;
        int r = 15;
        int xmax = 15;
        int ymax = 15;

        drowLine(length);

        System.out.println();

        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            System.out.print("+");
        }
        if (i == 0 && j <= ymax) {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        if (j == ymax) {
            System.out.print("^");
        }
        for (int j = ymax; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= xmax; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
                    drowEmptyLine(length);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                drowLine(length);
            }

            public static void drowLine ( int n){
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
            }

            public static void drowEmptyLine ( int n){
                System.out.print("");
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
                    System.out.print("# ");
                }
                System.out.print('#');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the greater coordinate of the start position + the length is greater than 15 then increase xmax and ymax by the difference.

Comment: +1 for actually trying the assignment and posting your code. You have no idea how many people copy-paste their assignment question into a Stack Overflow question with nothing else.

Comment: ... although that said, what's your actual question? I don't see one here.

Comment: side note: they ask you to use command line parameters (the args[] array), not parsing the standard input

Comment: yeah thx. I try to understand before getting 100%. My problem is that I cant seem to get java to ask me where i want to place the square. I want it to ask the user for the initial coordinates of the square. So if I enter (3,4) it will place the square at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a little grave digging apparently :-)

To start with we have to grab the args given on the CLI and turn them to sanitized ints.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

            if (size < 1 || size > 30) {
                System.out.println("Setting size to 5");
                size = 5;
            }

            if (x < 0 || x > 30) {
                System.out.println("Setting x to 2");
                x = 2;
            }

            if (y < 0 || y > 30) {
                System.out.println("Setting y to 2");
                y = 2;
            }

            int height = Math.max(y + size + 1, 15);
            int width = Math.max(x + size + 1, 15);
            drawSquare(height, width, size, x, y);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

To draw the square we have to go top to bottom because we are using the CLI. Alternatively one could fill a large `char[][]` and print it out at the end - top to bottom :-).
The whole '-1' in parts of the code is basically due to the fact that arrays and such are 0-based.

```java
    static void drawSquare(int height, int width, int size, int x, int y) {
        for (int line = height -1 ; line >= 0; line--) {
            drawline(line, size, x, y, width);
        }
    }
```

Lines can be categorized in either empty lines, those representing the top and bottom of the square, and those representing the square's content.

```java
    static void drawline(int line, int size, int x, int y, int width) {
        if (line > y + size - 1 || line < y) {
            drawEmptyLine(width);
        } else if (line == y + size - 1 || line == y) {
            drawBorder(x, size, width);
        } else {
            drawContent(x, size, width);
        }
    }
```

Empty lines are easy:

```java
    static void drawEmptyLine(int width) {
        draw(emptyLine(width));
    }

    static char[] emptyLine(int width) {
        char[] dots = new char[width];
        Arrays.fill(dots, 0, width, '.');
        return dots;
    }

    static void draw(char[] chars) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(chars.length);
        sb.append(chars);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

The border and content lines simply replace the dots in an empty line by some hashes:

```java
    static void drawContent(int x, int size, int width) {
        char[] dots = emptyLine(width);
        dots[x] = '#';
        dots[x + size - 1] = '#';
        draw(dots);
    }

    static void drawBorder(int x, int size, int width) {
        char[] dots = emptyLine(width);
        Arrays.fill(dots, x, x + size, '#');
        draw(dots);
    }
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named Shape with an abstract method named print.
From this class inherit three classes - Square, Triangle and Circle.
Square will have 4 points with coordinates (10,20) (30,40) (50,60) (70,80)
Triangle will have 3 points with coordinates (10,20) (30,40) (50,60)
Circle will have a point and a radius (25) with coordinates (50,60)
Implement the print method of shape to print to the console the points/radius of the shape (the properties of the specific shape).
Have an array of Shapes with three instances of each type of shape.
Loop over the array and call print, to print each one of the shapes.
Use a console input to input the data to each one of the shapes type.

Comment: I see no mention of triangle or circle in the question. I fail to see how this answers the question.